# Como passar parâmetro "IsAuthenticated" para actionfilter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Estou tentando de alguma maneira de passar parâmetro para **actionfilter**.

Por favor, segue o código:

**Controller:**

```
[LogActionFilter(IsAuthenticated = Request.IsAuthenticated)]
//Tentativa 1 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated
```

**ActionFilter:**

```
public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    { 
      etc...
```

Recebo esse erro:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Controller.HttpContext'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matheus, uma alternativa para você seria não passar o `Request.IsAuthenticated` como parâmetro para o seu `LogActionFilter` e sim usar o `IsAuthenticated` dentro do seu `OnActionExecuted`, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        Debugger.Log(0, "", "");
    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: Resolveu problema aqui, obrigado @Pablo Tondolo de Vargas